# Deleting MySQL records using checkboxes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox, foreach, sql-delete

I'm trying to delete MySQL records in PHP using check boxes. I echoed each line and everything seems fine. The values and formats of the variables and arrays are correct.

But when I tried to echo `$delete` (which is the `DELETE` query) using `VAR_DUMP()`, it displays `bool(false)` (which means it doesn't get the value of the variable `$emailID` passed to it, right?). Why?

```
if (isset($_POST['deleteUser']) && isset($_POST['marked_user']))
{

    $marked_user = $_POST['marked_user'];


    foreach($marked_user as $user => $emailID)
    {
        $emailID = (int)$emailID;
        $delete = $base -> query( "DELETE FROM tickets.allowed_users WHERE allowed_users.emailID = '$emailID'");

    }
        header('Location: viewTickets.php?viewType=U');
}
```

This is the HTML part from a separate PHP file:

```
echo "<form action='addUser.php' method='POST'><table class='results3' align='center' cellspacing='0'>
            <tr><th class='head' id='headleft'  width='10%'></th>
                <th class='head' id='headright' colspan='4'>E-mail</th></tr>";

            while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql) )
            {
                $email = $row['email'];
                $emailID = $row['emailID'];
                echo "<tr><td width='1%' class='results'><input type='checkbox' name='marked_user[]' value='$emailID'></td>
                        <td class='results' colspan='4'>" . $row['email']."</td></tr>";
            }
                echo "<td colspan='3'><input type='submit' class='button' name='deleteUser' value='Delete'></td></form>";
```

And this is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE allowed_Users
(
 emailID INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY( emailID )
);
```

Comment: SQL Injection vulnerability. Use query bindings instead of directly inserting user supplied values, ESPECIALLY for deletes. Can you supply more code with your block 1? I see a closing script tag in there with little context.

Comment: And `$base` is a proper MySQLi object? Can check with `print_r($base)`.

Comment: the script tag doesnt belong there. it's just misplaced. 
`$base` belongs to a class in a separate file that handles php connections. That code I'm asking is only a part of a ticketing system I'm working on. Block1 code is just that. I have another `if isset` function somewhere in that php file where it belongs to that does other things(insert user) and it's working perfectly fine.

Comment: I edited my code and removed the `INSERT` statement to avoid confusion since those are just sample records. I also posted a working code as an answer to my question. I made it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to concatenate a string like this:

```
foreach($marked_user as $user => $emailID)
    {
        $emailID = (int)$emailID;
        $delete = $base -> query( "DELETE FROM tickets.allowed_users WHERE allowed_users.emailID = " . $emailID);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST["marked_user"]); $i++) {
 $base -> query("DELETE FROM tickets.allowed_users WHERE allowed_users.emailID = '".$_POST["marked_user"][$i]."'");
}
```

Check if that works. If it does, manipulate the imput data so your code does not remain vulnerable to SQL injections.

Answer (score 0):

Change this code

```
$delete = $base -> query( "DELETE FROM tickets.allowed_users WHERE allowed_users.emailID  = '$emailID'");
```

To

```
$delete = $base->query( "DELETE FROM tickets.allowed_users WHERE allowed_users.emailID = '$emailID'");
```

Comment: removing the spaces between `-` and `>` doesn't change anything. My other queries look like that and it's working perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to make `foreach` work so I used `for` loop instead. So there. I think I can rely more on `for` loop.

```
if(isset($_POST['delete']))
{       
    for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['marked']);$i++)
    {
        $del_id=$_POST['marked'][$i];
        $delete = $base -> query( "DELETE FROM allowed_users WHERE emailID = '$del_id'");   
    }
    header('Location: viewTickets.php?viewType=U');
}
```

Comment: As per the comments on the question, this code is insecure, and may allow arbitrary queries from anonymous users to be run on your database. At the very least, it is trivial to empty this table entirely using this vuln.